# Why does UIKeyboard appear when press cancel button on UISearchbar?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, uisearchbar

I am using following code for adding `UISearchBar` in iOS7 and `UISearchBar` appearance is fine.But problem is when press cancel button on `UISearchBar` then `UIKeyboard` appeared.Why its happen?Please help me.

```
CGRect searchFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, 64, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0f);
self.mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:searchFrame];
self.mySearchBar.delegate = self;
self.mySearchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleDefault;
self.mySearchBar.placeholder = @"search items;
self.mySearchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.mySearchBar];
```

Comment: While you press cancel button in UISearchbar than - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar; method calls. Set Hide Keyboard code in that method.

Comment: @Mayur,its not working..

Comment: make sure cancel button is active. It will be active only if you have entered any text. If its blank than cancel button will not work.

Comment: @Mayur,First time my cancel button is not active.At that time I pressed cancel button then keyboard appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:` `UISearchBarDelegate` method. If you want the keyboard to go away you would do something like:

```
- (void) searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your issue now.

When there is not text entered at that time cancel button will be disabled. So if you try to press it than it will consider SearchBar text area & Keyboard will appear.

While you enter the text than Cancel button will be active & than it will work.

Hope you'll get the solution from this.

Comment: Can you give me sample code??how to disable cancel button if there is not text entered?